# how to remove everything between 2 words if a word is between them?

Tags: notepad++

i have posts like:

```
XXX
megafilesfactory.com/d7e1fbb7a7478a4e/Hidemyip6119.la.zip
YYY

XXX
google.com/d7e1fbb7a7478a4e/Hidemyip6119.la.zip
YYY

XXX
megafilesfactory.com/d7e1fbb7a7478a4e/Hidemyip6119.la.zip
YYY
```

All urls are between XXX and YYY.

I want to have only XXXYYY if a url with google.com is between it. So, everything else must get deleted and the above post will be changed to:

```
XXX
google.com/d7e1fbb7a7478a4e/Hidemyip6119.la.zip
YY
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^XXX\R(?!.*\bgoogle\.com\b).*\RYYY\R*
```

and replace with an empty string.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `XXX` - a hard-cosed string `XXX`
- `\R`  - a linebreak
- `(?!.*\bgoogle\.com\b).*` - a line consisting of any 0+ chars but without a whole word `google.com`
- `\R` - a linebreak
- `YYY` - hardcoded string `YYY`
- `\R*` - zero or more linebreaks.

[image]

Comment: Please provide feedback, it is important to know if the answer works for you or not.